# What kind of function allow me to find out the colour RGB components of any given pixel?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mouse, pixel

I got a picbox in my function which store

the image as bitmap,

i now need a function that can

find out the colour RGB components of any given pixel when i move my mouse on to it

what should i do to get this?

---

I have success to display the RGB and pixel in selected textbox
but when i move my mouse out side of the picture box
there's error msg came out:

Parameter must be positive and < Width.
Parameter name: x

i try to use If e.X > 300 Then e.X = 300
but it said "e.X" is for read only

My Code current looks like this:

```
    If pixBox1.Image Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    txtColourPixel.Text = String.Format("x,y = {0},{1}; Color={2}", e.X, e.Y, DirectCast(pixBox1.Image, Bitmap).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You COULD do it like this:

**UPDATE:** SOMETIMES the Move handler gives coordinates OUTSIDE of the actual image. Oned could handle this, or just ignore:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.ShowDialog()
    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = ofd.FileName
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Try
        TextBox1.Text = String.Format("x,y = {0},{1}; Color={2}", e.X, e.Y, DirectCast(PictureBox1.Image, Bitmap).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToString)
    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        ' this can happen, we just swallow it and show an error text
        TextBox1.Text = "out of bounds"
    End Try
End Sub
```

`GetPixel` is the method you want.

Comment: igrimpe : but how can i display the x,y?

Comment: @AnsonAştepta: Please explain? The sample code DOES display the coordinates of the point, the mouse is over.

Comment: i try to apply your example in a new form , i'm able to open up the image i want , but i want the x,y pixel display inside a textbox or label, how can i do that? many thanks :)

Comment: Replace Console.WriteLine(...) with Textbox1.Text = String.Format(...)

Comment: @AnsonAştepta: Udated sample. But you should not use a textbox to SHOW infos - use a label instead.

Comment: also there's a error : Parameter must be positive and < Width.
Parameter name: x

Comment: The error makes no sense. Update your question and show the code you are actually using

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to the mouse move event to get the x, y location of the mouse when it moves.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx

Use `Bitmap.GetPixel` to retrieve the color at that location.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitmap.GetPixel to determine pixel color.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Then use Color's R, G and B components to get R, G abd B values:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.r.aspx